# Javascript confusion with console.log - Beginner Q

Tags: javascript, html

During my Springboard course my instructor had the following show up in his Web Browser Console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ0f4.png

I want the same results to show up in the Browser Console, however this is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqtbF.png

Why, in his code, was he able to have something show up in the console without the `console.log`? When I attempt this, nothing appears in the console. Also, why am I getting a 1 instead of "you are the worst :("?

I'm into the course only a few days and am still trying to grasp `console.log` and how VS code connects to a web browser when using HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: To clarify, I understand how the setTimeout function works. I just don't get why he can return something within the console without "console.log"

Comment: You are logging the return value of `setTimeout` which is the timeoutId. You can instead make your functions do the `console.log()` action and just run your functions without calling the `console.log()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why, in his code, was he able to have something show up in the console
> without the console.log?

The `diss` function will have the console.log, thats why its printing in console

> When I attempt this, nothing appears in the console. Also, why am I
> getting a 1 instead of "you are the worst :("?

This is because you are printing the return of `setTimeout`, return of setTimeout will be a positive integer, in your case its 1, that why you see that in console.

There is difference between your inststuctor and your code.

See instructor code line 38-40 there is no console.log

But your code in 8-10 has console.log

That makes the diff in output

Comment: This makes total sense now. Thank you I appreciate the help!!

Comment: @BerkleyOlmstead Consider accepting a answer which you feel helped to solve your question. That way the question doesnt stay open. You can also vote a question if you think its helpful. Thats how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

The lines of code you're seeing in the screenshot are Functions. Your instructor is calling a function called 'greet()' twice, and one called 'diss()' once.

Functions are just blocks of code that can be ran via a keyword, in this case, 'greet()' or 'diss()'. Programmers use them to keep make complex code easier to read.

Looking in the screenshot, you can see that it says 'app.js:2' to the right of the greeting, and 'app.js:6' to the right of the diss. If you went to those lines in the code, you'd see the missing console.log() statement.